# Remote workplace

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rdp, windows-sbs-2003

Windows 2003 Small business server has a Remote desktop protocol portal to act as a web vpn if you use IE 6 or later. Can you setup Remote workplace portal for Windows 2003 Standard via IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Web Workplace (RWW) is only available on Windows Small Business Server 2003 and 2008. It is really a good solution and is more secure than a VPN.

In Windows Server 2008 you also have the Terminal Services Gateway feature which, although it isn't the same as RWW, goes some of the way to providing the same features.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Remote workplace is only a feature of Windows 2003 Small Business server.  We use an SSL-VPN product like the SonicWall SSL-VPN 2000 to provide bookmarked RDP sessions to users.  A built-in option would be to use the PPTP VPN functionality of 2003 Standard and then have users RDP to their local desktops manually.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried windows server SBS before,
but in my workplace, i use windows server's RRAS feature to vpn in from home, and use it's remote desktop web connection (using IE6 and above, it's a feature under IIS) to connect to any box in the office.

Really simplifies my job alot.